# Couple of questions about composing query using PDO

Tags: php, sql, pdo, placeholder

I have two question about querying in pdo, **1st:** Which type of placeholders is better to use in pdo, for example comparing this:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT model FROM cars WHERE brand = :brand');
$stmt->bindValue(':brand', $brand, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();
```

and this:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT model FROM cars WHERE brand = ?');
$stmt->bindValue(1, $brand, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();
```

and it is allowed to use both types of place holders in the same query.

---

**2nd:** If I'm willing to use some function to compose a generic query, something like:

```
public function genQuery($qType, qFieldsArray, qTablesArray, qWhereArray, qOrderArray, qGroupArray){
    switch($type){
        case 'select';
          //Call to slctFunction
          break;
        case 'update';
          //Call to updtFunction
          break;
        //**etc..
}
```

Please correct me if I am wrong, but as long as I am binding the values of user-input data separately in the `slctFunction`, `updtFunction`, etc.. and not injecting them into the query directly then I am not making it vulnerable against sql-injection, Right?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: May I know why the question was voted down?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question 1: You can use either named or numbered parameters, but you can't use both in the same statement. From [`PDO::prepare`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php):

> You cannot use both named and question mark parameter markers within the same SQL statement; pick one or the other parameter style.

I think named parameters are better, since they're self-documenting and not going to be impacted if you update the query to add more parameters.

Question 2: You're correct, using bound parameters instead of interpolating values into the query protects you from SQL injection.

Answer (score 0):

First question makes no sense. There is no all-"better" approach. Each is good for it's own use. Positional placeholders are indispensable as they can make your code less bloated, instead of writing each field name a dozen times.
Named are good because several placeholders with same name can be bound to just single variable. 
By the way, the latter has been made keeping in mind the situation where you can pass just whole $_POST array in execute. In such a case named placeholders can shorten your code. But the usual case when array keys are written by hand, like

```
$sql  = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE field1=:foo AND field2=:baz";
$data = DB::getAll($sql, array('foo'=>$foo, 'baz'=>$baz));
```

they make no sense and have to be written as

```
$sql  = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE field1=? AND field2=?";
$data = DB::getAll($sql, array($foo, $baz));
```

to make your code **DRY**

To answer if you can use them mixed - honestly, you can try and see it yourself in seconds.

Second one is better. However, some your premises are *bad*.

> as long as I am binding the values of **user-input** data

You are WRONG.
There should be no separation on the data source. This is very cornerstone principle of safety: NOT ONLY notorious and vague "user-input" but EVERY value. Eevery value that goes into query, have to be either hardcoded or substituted by placeholder. NO exceptions.

This also makes your generic function **unsafe**. Not to mention that the very idea of such a function is spoiled by design. Why do you want it? To spare yourself a word of two? And what you get in return? An **obfuscated** gibberish out of precious SQL and shackles you bound yourself in. What are examples of using this function? Did you try to see them in action? Did you try to compare them with regulart SQL?

What about queries like JOINTS, INSERT DELAYED, etc? Are you going to write FULL SQL dialect in PHP?

For *really* simple queries you should use ORM. It will make your code indeed short but still readable. But for all the goodness sake - abandon the idea of such a builder.